# Is there a way to listen to live HF communications using the internet?

Tags: hf, receiver, internet

I'd like to be able to show people what a QSO sounds like without having my transceiver available.

Is there a way I can listen to amateurs talking in real-time (or using Morse code) on the HF bands using my internet connection and the speakers on my computer?

Comment: Live, or is recorded okay? Long QSO, or quick QSO? Is simulated CW okay? Bottom line, more details would go a long ways.

Comment: Darn, that takes away the Youtube videos...

Comment: http://websdr.org/ or http://sdrspace.com/ are great places

Comment: @Dan That could be an answer!

Comment: @KevinReid true, sorry. I posted as answer

Comment: If you have Skype check out: [N8AD HF Remote over Skype or landline](http://www.hfremote.us/).

Answer (score 21):

My two favorite locations for listening online are:

- http://websdr.org/

  - WebSDR was first conceived as a means to make the 25 m radio telescope at Dwingeloo available to many radio amateurs for EME reception. In order to test a preliminary version of the software without using the 25m dish, a shortwave WebSDR was set up on Christmas Eve 2007 at the radio club of the University of Twente. After further development, its existence was publicly announced in April 2008. Interest for the project has been large since then, and many amateurs worldwide have expressed an interest in setting up their own WebSDR server. In November 2008, a beta testing phase has started with a few selected stations. By now, the software is made available to anyone serious about setting up a server; contact the author, PA3FWM, for information. A WebSDR server consists of a PC running Linux and the WebSDR server software, a fast internet connection (about a hundred kbit/s uplink bandwidth per listener), and some radio hardware to feed antenna signals into the PC. This radio hardware is typically a quadrature mixer connected to the PC's soundcard, like the popular SoftRock kits. [There is also an experimental version of this site hosted in the Netherlands that uses HTML5 rather than Java.](http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/)
- http://sdrspace.com/

  - SDRSpace is a place for folks using SDR-RADIO software to share their radio on the web. SDR-RADIO.com is a Windows console for Software Defined Radio (SDR) receivers and transceivers. Designed for the commercial, government, amateur radio and short-wave listener communities, the software provides a powerful interface for all SDR users.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting: [http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/](http://websdr.ewi.utwente.nl:8901/), while it is listed on websdr.org, is unique among the WebSDR sites in not requiring Java supported by the browser.

Comment: @KevinReid I added it (especially since that is the one I use!) :P

Comment: One downside to all the websdr solutions: the original question wants to listen to a QSO, which implies to me 'both sides'. Using a websdr will usually get you only one side of the QSO unless the other party is really close to the websdr antenna allowing reception via groundwave.

Comment: http://w7rna.dyndns-remote.com:18901/ also has an HTML5 interface, maybe that is becoming more common now.